# Defining HTML-like tags as TeX macros

Tags: punctuation, html, catcodes

I have to admit, my catcode skill are not that good.

I'm working with some templates that will be filled in by a programme (`HTML::Template`, made for `HTML` but very handy for LaTeX as well). I'd like my template to be compilable even without the tags being substituted.

Tags are of the form `<TMPL_#1 #2>` and `</TMPL_#1>`, any ideas as to how one can make these into macros themselfs?

Here is my current attempt where ` does not work (and is thus outcommented) plus the catcode change affects the entire document whis is not really what I want.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

% enable this to make a WEB template compilable
% he <TMPL_VAR ..>'s will be replaced by the template system
\catcode`\_=\active                     
\let\_\textunderscore%
\catcode`<=\active
\gdef<TMPL_#1 #2>{\texttt{\textless TMPL\_#1 #2\textgreater}}
%\def</TMPL_#1>{\texttt{\textless /TMPL\_#1\textgreater}}

\begin{document}

<TMPL_VAR TEST>

<TMPL_IF NAME=TEST>
something
%</TMPL_IF>

\end{document}
```

any suggestions?

Comment: You could look at typehtml or for a more complete version xmltex

Comment: `\gdef<TMPL_#1 #2>` just defines `<` and defines it so that it has to be followed by TMPL, and the commented redefinition would define `<` so that it _had_ to be followed by /TMP

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

% enable this to make a WEB template compilable
% he <TMPL_VAR ..>'s will be replaced by the template system

\catcode`<=\active
\catcode`_=12
\gdef<#1>{\texttt{\textless #1\textgreater}}


\begin{document}

<TMPL_VAR TEST>

<TMPL_IF NAME=TEST>
something
</TMPL_IF>

\end{document}
```

If the catcode change should be local. just move the

```
\catcode`<=\active
\catcode`_=12
```

to the begin code of some environment eg `\begin{template}` .. `\end{template}` then surround you `<>` blocks with this environment

Or if you do not want to mess with the catcode of `_` you can use

```
\catcode`<=\active

\gdef<#1>{\texttt{\textless \detokenize{#1}\textgreater}}
```

Comment: This of course kills `$x_2$`, I'm not use if where will be any math in the templated documents, so I was hoping to avoid this.

Comment: @daleif as I say you can easily make the catcode change local to an environment if you want an environment that uses `<>` but no math. If you want an environment that mixes `<>` syntax and math can you give an example?

Comment: @dale updated to use `\detokenize` rather than recatcode `_`

Comment: As it sits now, no I do not have an example. In reality it will not be that much of a deal, once the templating system has made its substitutions all the `<TMPL...>` stuff is gone. This was only to make the template itself compilable for when one is writing the template. The `\detokenize` version works well